# How to read this component mechanical drawings

Tags: schematics, footprint

I am adding a display to my small hobby project. And due to size and cost constraint the choice falls on Chinese QG-2864KLBLG01 OLED display. Everything about it seems to be perfect except one small detail -- I am really not sure whether I am reading their specifications correctly. The spec is available [here](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1810010422_Shenzhen-Allvision-Tech-QG-2864KLBLG01_C90547.pdf). And the part that I am talking about is the mechanical drawing from which I am drawing a footprint. The part that I am not clear about whether pin 1 is on the left side when I look at the front side or at the back side. There is no mention of this (nor correct footprint drawing) in this specification. So I hope community can help me to figure this out -- what is the right footprint for this 1-30 (left to right) or 30-1?

[image: mechanical drawing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is 1-30 from the top image.

This is notable from the small, black, rectangular, dashed box (the Chip On Glass) being *dashed*. Dashed lines imply inside or underneath, so this chip-on-glass (cable) has to be on the *bottom*.

And the middle image (viewing the display from it's right edge) shows the little rectangle on the right side, indicating the bottom.